# Pine,: to create an indicator that merges two moving averages from two symbols to compare their movement, both using the same scale

Tags: pine-script

What technique can be used that allows the moving averages to use the same scale? I'm not sure that this counts as normalizing the scale as the intention is that the price of one symbol is used as the the scale.

Normally when to different moving averages are in one indicator, they are both seem flat as the values are so different.

The inattention is to compare closely correlated securities and see how their moving averages interact.

Many thanks,
Theo

Answer (score 0):

We can get the high low of the two symbols for one year . Then we can scale the prices of average to 100 using high-low. Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Indicator Merge By Rohit")
var ph=0.0
symbol1 = input.symbol("BTCUSDT","Symbol1")
symbol2 = input.symbol("DOGEUSDT","Symbol2")
period=input.int(20,"Period")
[hi1,lo1]=request.security(symbol1, "12M", [high,low], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
[hi2,lo2]=request.security(symbol2, "12M", [high,low], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
close1=request.security(symbol1, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
close2=request.security(symbol2,timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
sma1=ta.sma(close1,period)
sma2=ta.sma(close2,period)
var sma1fixed=0.0
sma1fixed:=(sma1-lo1)*100/(hi1-lo1)
var sma2fixed=0.0
sma2fixed:=(sma2-lo2)*100/(hi2-lo2)
plot(sma1fixed,color=color.red)
plot(sma2fixed,color=color.blue)
```